# Is there any way to use scanf() with an editable default text in C?

Tags: c, printf, scanf, console-application

I'm trying to get a line of data from the user, but I want to preload some default data in the line so the user doesn't need to type a whole lot, it's enough to edit the line.

The point would be so that the user can fix typos in a line of data.

Comment: `scanf` cannot do this, but an input-line-editing library such as [readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) might be able to.